# css3 transitions on links show blue colour on load

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

On my website (http://amosjackson.com), the navigation links use css transitions to change colour when the user hovers over them. Despite setting the colour to white in the stylesheet, when the page loads, the links are blue (default colour for links). This then transitions back into the normal white and does not happen again unless the page is refreshed. I could not reproduce this problem elsewhere on the page and this error does not occur when on the contact page (one of the links in the nav bar).

EDIT: Error only occurs in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `style.css`, under the class `.links`, remove the CSS transition. This should stop the initial transition, but also affects the fade out.

```
.links{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-family:goudy;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:40px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Also try setting `a {color: white}` and see if that has an affect.

Answer (score 2):

First use this in your HTML:

```
<body class="preload">
```

Then add this CSS:

```css
.preload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Finally, you can either use jQuery or vanilla JS for the JavaScript part:

jQuery:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

Vanilla JS:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    var element = document.getElementById("body");
    element.classList.remove("preload");
});
```

Comment: It might be better if you put in a bit of an explanation of what the code you have provided is doing.

Comment: In our HTML file we added class "preload", wich have !important rules in CSS file, that says there is no any transitions before this class "preload" exists. And then in JS file we writing a rule that remove class "preload" from the body tag after the document is ready.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but this is what I do and theres no `.js` involved.

For  just for a style or two you can manually include them in the head of the page like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>
        nav a.btn {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

allowing the browser to render those styles immediately and in turn prevents FOUC from happening - for larger amounts of styles you should look at a pre-processor that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are still tracking this question, :( anyway, answer this to mark down the issue i have faced as well.

This could be caused by the <link> tag, in which the style classes are defined, I just moved

```
a {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

from <link> reference to embedded <style> tag, that issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by including the CSS styles in `<head>` instead of the bottom of `<body>`. It was loading the styles after all the html loading.